# Writing Data in Sql table from a text file using Pandas Module

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to read some data from a text file and write it down in a Sql server table using Pandas Module and FOR LOOP. Below is my code..

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    Trusted_Connection = 'Yes',
    Driver = driver,
    Server = '***********',
    Database = 'Sullins_Data'
    )

def createdata():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
    'insert into Sullins_Datasheet(Part_Number,Web_Link) values(?,?);',
    (a,j))
    conn.commit()


a = pd.read_csv('check9.txt',header=None, names=['Part_Number','Web_Links'] ) # 2 Columns, 8 rows
b = pd.DataFrame(a)
p_no = (b['Part_Number'])
w_link  = (b['Web_Links'])
# print(p_no)
for i in p_no:
    a = i
    for l in w_link:
        j = l
    createdata()
```

As you can see from the code that I have created 2 variables a and j to hold the value of both the columns of the text file one by one and write it in the sql table.
But after running the code I have got only the last row value in the table out of 8 rows.
When I used createdate function inside w_link for loop, it write the duplicate value in the table.
Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: i think happening like a is reading first line and then l is reading rest of line on column 2. so i think it is working like abbbbbabbbbbbabbbbb so it is taking 1 a value and then all b value so it is inserting last value it found.

Comment: you can check that by printing variable a,j and then please tell if it is printing as i said

Comment: exactly. same thing happening as you said.

Comment: actualy for loop is itrating first one and due to nested loop it directly going to next column and making list of all component then again coming to first after complete

Comment: you should use while loop to iterate through your colum

Answer (score 0):

here is sample of how your code is working

```
 a = 0
b = 0
ptr=['s','d','f','e']
pt=['a','b','c','d']
for i in ptr:
    a=i
    print(a,end='')
    for j in pt:
        b=j
        print(b,end='')
```